# Custom error page configured in IIS for code 400 (bad request) is ignored

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, custom-error-pages

For my website I configured some custom error pages.
If I generate a 404, the redirect works fine.
When hitting a 400, the "bad request" text shows up instead of the configured URl.

As a test I copied the URL from 404 to 400. No change.
Then I changed the redirect to a file. No change.

Any ideas?

Comment: For any future readers of this discussion. You need to first determine what module of Windows/IIS gives you the 400 error page. Had it been http.sys (caused by factors such as oversize headers) or your web framework (caused by SOAP/REST errors), the way to customize that error page is closed or opened. Without this in mind, you wouldn't understand why some 400 can be customized and others not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753103(v=ws.10)) is your answer: this Microsoft site says re configuring custom errors in IIS6 that

> The following errors are not
>   customizable: 400, 403.9, 411, 414,
>   500, 500.11, 500.14, 500.15, 501, 503,
>   and 505.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although it's a good answer, it defenatly is not a sollution :(

Comment: as of 03/07/2019 
statusCode
Required integer attribute.
Specifies the number of the HTTP status code for which you want to create a custom error message. Acceptable values are from 400 through 999.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/settings-schema/ms689487(v=vs.90)

Answer (score 7):

I've run in to the same problem, and found this on msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690497.aspx

I'm not sure if this will work on IIS6, but it certainly works on IIS7.
You need to configure **httpErrors**, not the custom errors

```
<system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <error statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1" path="_path" responseMode="Redirect" />
      </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```

OR

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985327/asp-net-web-api-httpresponseexception-400-bad-request-hijacked-by-iis)

Answer (score 1):

In 2020 it will work just like that `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1" />
      ...
      <error statusCode="400" prefixLanguageFilePath="YOUR_PATH" path="YOUR_HTML_FILE" responseMode="File" />
    ...
```

> statusCode
>
> Required integer attribute.
>
> Specifies the number of the HTTP status code for which you want to create a custom error message. Acceptable values are from 400 through 999.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/settings-schema/ms689487(v=vs.90)

Note that bad URL like https://stackoverflow.com/% still won't be customizable and one will get the simple **Bad Request** message coming from the IIS Kernel (Error Code 400).

More on that here
https://serverfault.com/questions/257680/properly-handle-iis-request-with-percent-sign-in-url

Comment: There is usually nothing called "IIS Kernel". People commonly say http.sys or Windows HTTP API/service.

Answer (score 0):

Check what's in your web.config file in the `customErrors` section. That has a `defaultRedirect` attribute, and an `error` subtag with a `redirect` attribute. These can conflict with your other configuration settings in IIS.

Comment: I have configured it the same as in IIS. Nevertheless, if the page would be incorrect, I would get a 404 is it not?