# Customize error 400 (Bad Request) avoid IIS-8 intercepting it

Tags: iis, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

The request is intercepted by the IIS, and it never hits my application.

I want that my Error Handling to manage this error, not IIS. Is this possible?

I've tried many things, including these:

1. In my Web.config: `<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>`
2. Also this configuration:

> ```
> <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough">
>     <remove statusCode="400"/>
>     <error statusCode="400" path="http://www.google.com" responseMode="Redirect"/>
> </httpErrors>
> ```

3. From the [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731570%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) (IIS 7, nothing on IIS 8 documentation):

> You cannot customize the following HTTP error messages: 400, 403.9,
> 411, 414, 500, 500.11, 500.14, 500.15, 501, 503, and 505.

**Here we can replicate the error:**

https://stackoverflow.com/ + %%% (you should copy the entire link, with the invalid characters included).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are out of luck with this as the following thread already shows: https://serverfault.com/questions/257680/properly-handle-iis-request-with-percent-sign-in-url

One possible solution is to handle this error code at your load balancer (which of course will not be IIS based).

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to
[Custom error page configured in IIS for code 400 (bad request) is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268592/custom-error-page-configured-in-iis-for-code-400-bad-request-is-ignored/64915366#64915366)

in short the redirect with `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" ...` works already also for HTTP 400 / bad request and one can customize it except for the errors blocked by the IIS Kernel (for example bad URL)

I am not sure about the version of IIS where it started working. I tested it on IIS 10.

The example `https://stackoverflow.com/%` still won't work, but

`return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);`
will work as expected (it won't be blocked from the IIS Kernel)